# Get View Model property tfrom service using depdendency injection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have viewmodel as follows

```
public VMTest
{
  [RequiredIf("depdendentproperty", "1")]
  public int property1 {get;set;}
  public int depdendentproperty 
  {
    get 
    {
        return IMyservice.GetData(property1);
    }

  }
}
```

i want to call `Myservice` method through dependency injection. but for this i need to add a overloaded constructor for viewmodel that doesn't seem right. My query is how to get property value of viewmdel from service with or without dependency injection. once solution is to add default constructor in service and call service method directly. Please suggest

Actually my requirement is to implement it through get Method. To elaborate I am applying RequiredIf attribute on property1. whenever property1 is validated it depends on dependentproperty

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the paradigma of what a `ViewModel` should do. You could prepare it at least on the `Controller` or a `Method` in your service that returns the `ViewModel`.

Add the namespace:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

And try something like this action method sample:

```
public IActionResult GetData()
{
    var service = this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMyservice>();
    var property1Value = 1;
    var result = new VMTest()
    {
       property1 = property1Value ,
       dependentyProperty = service.GetData(property1Value )
    };

    return View(result);
}
```

In the controller scope you can access the [`HttpContext.RequestServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) property which is a representation of the native `IoC` container on the [asp.net-core](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core).

Comment: Thank you I need to implement it through get method. I have updated the question

Comment: @Zia getting it through the get method is not advised. The provided answer is correct in its assessment You will probably need to create a model binder to populate the property before it is passed to teh action.

Comment: @Nkosi do you know how to get the container instance from any scope on a asp.net core project?

Comment: @FelipeOriani if going the custom model binder route then you would have access to HttpContext via the [ModelBindingContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelbindingcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.0) which mean you can access the RequestServices. Reference [Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-model-binder-sample)